# Generating double linear sequence in Haskell

Tags: beginner, haskell

Need some comments on making the below code more effective. I'm pretty new to Haskell.

The sequence in `generateSeq` is generated by the rule that if `x` is in the sequence then `x*2+1` and `x*3+1` are also in the sequence.

`getNumberAt` gets the n'th number in the (sorted) generated sequence.

The code works but somehow I feel that I'm overcomplicating this. Any pointers are appreciated!

```
    generateSeq :: Int -> [Integer]
    generateSeq x
        | x == 0 = [1]
        | otherwise = sort $ prev++toAppend
                         where prev = generateSeq(x-1)
                               toAppend = [next*2+1,next*3+1]
                               next = head $ drop(x-1) prev

    getNumberAt :: Int -> Integer
    getNumberAt n = nub(generateSeq n)!!n


    -- Test this!
    main =
       print $ getNumberAt 321
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plus points for including top-level signatures (just missing for `main`). Some style nits - in Haskell it's uncommon to omit spaces between a function and its argument, rather than `drop(x-1)` it's more common to write `drop (x-1)`. And include spaces after commas in lists.

More importantly, as you probably observed, your method is quite inefficient. Just try to compute its value for 4000 or so. First, you sort the sequence every time. Second, you generate the whole sequence again in each step, just a bit longer.

For the latter, a solution is to [*memoize*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Memoization) the results, so that you compute each such intermediate list only once. This would look something like:

```
import Data.List

generateSeq :: Int -> [Integer]
generateSeq x
    | x == 0 = [1]
    | otherwise = sort $ prev ++ toAppend
                     where prev = generatedSeqs !! (x - 1)
                           toAppend = [next*2 + 1, next*3 + 1]
                           next = head $ drop (x-1) prev

generatedSeqs :: [[Integer]]
generatedSeqs = map (map head . group . generateSeq) [0..]

getNumberAt :: Int -> Integer
getNumberAt n = (generatedSeqs !! n) !! n
```

For the former, repeated sorting: Let's consider, how would a human create such sequence. Probably she would keep two lists. One would some part of the sequence, and the other would be candidates yet to be added to the sequence. At each step, the smallest candidate *n* is appended, and *2*n+1* and *3*n+1* added to the candidates. Translating this into code yields

```
import Data.Set

a002977_list :: [Integer]
a002977_list = loop $ singleton 1
  where
    loop set = x : loop (set' <> fromList [2*x + 1, 3*x + 1])
      where
        (x, set') = deleteFindMin set
```

The argument to the helper function is a [`Set`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.8.1/docs/Data-Set.html#t:Set) of candidates, which provides an efficient way for picking the smallest element.

You probably wonder why I named the function `a002977_list`. The sequence is of course a known one and is described, together with code samples how to generate it (the above code is adapted from there), at [OESIS](https://oeis.org/A002977).

But I strongly encourage you to try to improve your solution first, before looking there.

Comment: Nice. What's the <> operator?

Comment: Operator [`<>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:-60--62-) is a synonym for `mappend` from `Monoid`.

Answer (score 4):

Repeatedly sorting is asympotically slower than keeping a sorted data structure, `nub` takes quadratic time, `head . drop (x-1)` = `(!!x)`, and try to use library-defined recursion combinators instead of explicitly using recursion.

```
import qualified Data.Set as S

generateSeq :: [Integer]
generateSeq = unfoldr (fmap foo . S.minView) $ singleton 1 where
  foo :: (Integer, S.Set Integer) -> (Integer, S.Set Integer)
  foo (x, s) = (x, S.insert (2*x+1) $ S.insert (3*x+1) s)
```

*looks up comonad stuff on a hunch*

```
import qualified Data.Set as S
import Control.Comonad

generateSeq :: [Integer]
generateSeq = unfoldr ((fmap . extend . uncurry) foo . S.minView) $ singleton 1 where
  foo :: Integer -> S.Set Integer -> S.Set Integer
  foo x = S.insert (2*x+1) . S.insert (3*x+1)
```

Comment: Comonads are probably a bit overkill for a Haskell beginner...

Comment: That's why I left the first version in place.